# Пагинация. Как поменять цвет активной страницы в пагинации?

Tags: javascript, java, css, jquery, thymeleaf

Пагинация. Есть цикл each вызывающийся thymeleaf'ом.

```
<div class ="pagination">
                  <ul id="light-pagination" class="pagination col-xl-12 justify-content-center">
                     <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
                     <tr th:each="numberOfPages,state : ${lenOfBlog}">
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="/blog" th:href="${numberOfPages}" > <td th:utext="${numberOfPages}"></td></a></li>
                     </tr>
                     <li class="page-item disabled"><a class="page-link" href="/blog" th:href="${numberOfPages}"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
```

Нужно цветом выделять страницу на которой я нахожусь в данный момент. Не пойму как это сделать, ведь, если я добавлю page-item-active, тот у меня будут все страницы выделенные. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Цикл вытаскивает новости с БД.

Далее оставшийся код

```
@RequestMapping("/blog/{pageNo}")
    public String showBlog(@PathVariable int pageNo, Model model){
        List<BlogModel> list=blogService.findPaginated(pageNo-1);
        List<BlogModel> list1=blogService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("allBlogs",list);
        ArrayList<Integer> numberOfPages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= (int)Math.ceil((float)list1.size()/5); i++ )
        {
            numberOfPages.add(i);
        }
        model.addAttribute("lenOfBlog",numberOfPages);
        return "blog";
    }
```

Модель:

```
  public BlogModel(String titleBlog, String textBlog, String categoryBlog, String dateBlog) {
        this.titleBlog = titleBlog;
        this.textBlog = textBlog;
      //  this.imageBlog = imageBlog;
        this.categoryBlog = categoryBlog;
        this.dateBlog = dateBlog;
    }
```

Comment: а где хранится номер текущей страницы?

Comment: @МихаилРебров добавил в пояснение, не знаю, то или не то. Если нет, то объясните что нужно подробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: через пару часов освобожусь и напишу ответ

Comment: @МихаилРебров благодарю, ожидаю